# Excess lines in the solution plot of vector ODE

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, vector, vector-calculus

I've got an ODE system, which I attempt to solve by two ways: solving the system itself, and using vector ODE.

Here is code of **first** way:

```
    θ[x_] := Boole[x >= 0]
    {R, L, C1, Rl, T, Um} := {500, 0.2, 2*10^(-10), 10^3, 10^(-3), 10};
    {t1, t2, t3} := {T/2, T/3, T/6};
    u1[t_] := Um/t3*(t*θ[t] - (t - t3) θ[t - t3] - (t - t2) θ[t - t2] + (t - t1) θ[t - t1])
    numsltn = NDSolve[{uC'[t] == u1[t]/(R*C1) - uC[t]/(R*C1) - iL[t]/C1, iL'[t] == uC[t]/L - Rl/L*iL[t],uC[0] == iL[0] == 0},
{uC, iL}, {t, -T, T}, Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", Method -> {{"ExplicitRungeKutta","DifferenceOrder" -> 4}, Automatic}}, StartingStepSize -> 1.5*10^(-6)]
    Plot[{Evaluate[uC[t] /. numsltn], Evaluate[iL[t]*1000 /. numsltn]}, {t, -T, T},
     PlotRange -> range,
     PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, AxesLabel -> {"t, s", "u, V\ni, mA"}, 
     PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{Red, Blue}, {"uC(t)", "iL(t)"}],
     GridLines -> gridset]
```

Here is the code of **second** way:

```
θ[x_] := Boole[x >= 0]
{R, L, C1, Rl, T, Um, n} := {500, 0.2, 2*10^(-10), 10^3, 10^(-3), 10, 
   1000};
{t1, t2, t3} := {T/2, T/3, T/6};
u1[t_] := Um/t3*(t*θ[t] - (t - t3) θ[t - t3] - (t - t2) θ[t - t2] + (t - t1) θ[t - t1])
A := {{-(R*C1)^(-1), -1/C1}, {1/L, -Rl/L}}
b[t_] := {u1[t]/(R*C1), 0}
xsolution = NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == A.x[t] + b[t], x[0] == {0, 0}},
x, {t, -T, T}, Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", Method -> {{"ExplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}, Automatic}}, StartingStepSize -> (3*t1/n)]
uC[t_] := Projection[xsolution[t], {1, 0}]
iL[t_] := Projection[xsolution[t], {0, 1}]
Plot[{uC[t], iL[t]*1000}, {t, -T, T},
 PlotRange -> range, GridLines -> gridset,
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, AxesLabel -> {"t, s", "u, V\ni, mA"}, 
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{Red, Blue}, {"uC(t)", "iL(t)"}]]
```

***Note**: "gridset" and "range" values are not specified in order to simplify code analysis.*

I have problem with plots: first case is okay, but in second i get odd horizontal lines what you can see in the images:
[image: ODE system method]
[image: Vector ODE method]

How do I get rid of those odd lines?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Projection does a projection, but it does NOT reduce the dimension. Therefore, you need to write: `uC[t_] := Projection[xsolution[t], {1, 0}][[1]]
iL[t_] := Projection[xsolution[t], {0, 1}][[2]]`

Comment: @DanielHuber Thank you very much! In mathematics and physics projection is often considered as a number (scalar product of vector being worked on and unit vector) so I couldn't guess that Projection[] is still a vector. Can you assume why developers decided to make non-one-dimensional return value type?

Comment: I can only guess. It may be more convenient in graphics where you want to project to a line or surface.

Comment: I think typically a [projection operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)) is considered to be a transformation $\mathbb{P}:V \to V$, so the return type should also be a member of the same vector space $V$. It sounds like you want `Dot` instead of `Projection`, which is used to represent the inner product!

Comment: @thorimur You're right, inner product could solve the problem. Also I discovered that I can do what I need without even `Projection[]` nor inner product operation:
`uC[t_] := xsolution[t][[1]]
iL[t_] := xsolution[t][[2]]` .

Comment: To moderators.
I disagree with the closure of this question for the following reasons.
1. First of all, it's not off-topic: the question is about plotting relared to functions gotten by differential equation solving so there are appropriate tags; the euation is vector ODE so there are also two vector tags. Thus, question is NOT off-topic.

Comment: 2. Further, the mistake is not "simple": there is no syntax errors, incorrect capitalizations, spelling mistakes, or other typographical errors. Problem of this question is caused by deep feature of how `Protection[]` function works.
3. Furthermore, this aspect is not described explicitly in documentation.
4. This question is very useful for ones who will try to plot ODE system solutions gotten by replacing system with single vector equation.